# disable query logging in rails 3.2.x for development?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I followed all topics on disabling SQL query logging for active record. Who knows how to disable it correctly in rails 3.2.x ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this a try - sends the active record logging to null:

```
if Rails.env.development?
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
end
```

Comment: works perfectly I could not edit my bad comment; this works ! thx